# Did Putin give this talk about the cultural preservation of European tradition, religion and race?

Tags: politics, russia, vladimir-putin

From @JPY_Kurdish, https://twitter.com/JPY_Kurdish/status/812759470669529088 with thousands of RTs and likes:

> Putin calls for cultural self preservation of European tradition,
>   religion & race, criticizing today's globalists who ruin God's
>   diversity.

Did Vladmir Putin give this talk?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, he gave the talk, and the translation is authentic.

A blog post [TRANSCRIPT: [Putin at] Meeting of the Valdai International Discussion Club [partial transcript]](http://russialist.org/transcript-putin-at-meeting-of-the-valdai-international-discussion-club-partial-transcript/) has a transcript matching the clip which was tweeted, and says that it's from the Valdai International Discussion Club, and was given on 19 September 2013. It gives a link to the YouTube video [Broadcast: Vladimir Putin's Speech at the Valdai Club's Plenary Meeting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PtsodE-ZkY).

The Wikipedia article on [Valdai International Discussion Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valdai_International_Discussion_Club) gave http://valdaiclub.com/ as its official home page, and it in turn links to https://www.youtube.com/user/ValdaiClub , the uploader of the video.

The BBC has an article about this speech: [Russia's Putin shines at Valdai summit as he castigates West](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-24170137). The bottom half discusses the content referred to in the tweet.